# Why is koa this.req.socket on('data', ... called only once?

Tags: node.js, koa

Upon uploading an image:

> curl -v --data-binary "@$HOME/Pictures/blue_red_pill.jpg" http://localhost:3234/image

On data event is called only once with part of the upload.  The curl command just hangs until a timeout.  This is the server code:

```
const router = require('koa-router')()

router.post('/image', function *() {
    yield new Promise(resolve => {
        const socket = this.req.socket
        let dataBuffer = new Buffer('', 'binary')
        socket.on('data', data => {
            console.log(data.length, data.toString('hex').substring(0, 14))
            dataBuffer = Buffer.concat([dataBuffer, data])
        })
        socket.on('end', () => {
            console.log('end')
            resolve()
        })
    })
})
```

The bytes are only part of the file but the hex is the correct for the beginning of the file:

```
49152 'ffd8ffe000104a'
```

Comment: I'm open to alternatives.. I just need to read post as binary data.

Comment: Nothing obvious jumped out at me, but forgetting to add an event handler for socket error is one way it can fail (and then hang) silently.